# soft lockup in user process and dead lock

Tags: drivers, linux-kernel, watchdog

I have one issue, at customer machine the user space process is hogging up the processor (soft lockup)along with 2 kernel process and dump stack trace showing RIP at _ticket_spin_lock in all 3 process.

As i know "If an user-space process had caused the soft-lockup, a line identifying the process by its pid would logged, followed by the contents of various CPU-registers without a call-trace of any sorts" but in my case i am getting dump stack trace for user process too.

is it coming from a misbehaving user space app? is it normal functionality of soft lockup? if is it functionality of soft lockup then how to resolve the issue?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

it is x86_64 machine and kernel is 3.1.10. I know all 3 process are waiting for _ticket_spin_lock. see :-

```
Aug 26 09:31:58 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115452.492033] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s! [virtio_shm/5/3:7874] 
Aug 26 09:32:00 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115455.404215] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#31 stuck for 23s! [kni_thread:6605] 
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172014] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [gis:14145]
```

here gis is my user space process but has call trace.

```
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172014] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [gis:14145]
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172017] Modules linked in: xt_sharedlimit xt_hashlimit ip_set_hash_ipport ip_set_hash_ipportip xt_NOTRACK ip_set_bitmap_port xt_sctp nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 xt_CT arpt_mangle ip_set_hash_ipnet xt_NFLOG xt_limit xt_hashcounter ip_set_hash_ipip xt_set ip_set_hash_ip deflate ctr twofish_x86_64 twofish_common camellia serpent blowfish cast5 des_generic cbc xcbc rmd160 crypto_null af_key iptable_mangle ip_set arptable_filter arp_tables iptable_raw iptable_nat nfnetlink_log nfnetlink ipt_ULOG ipt_PORTMAP af_packet zlib zlib_deflate sha512_generic sha256_generic sha1_generic md5 icp_qa_al pcie8120 rte_kni pfe_pep virtio_rte virtio_shm virtio_vtnet virtio_uio igb_uio virtio_ring virtio uio xt_tcpudp xt_state xt_pkttype nf_conntrack_control bonding binfmt_misc iptable_filter ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip_tables x_tables mperf ipmi_devintf ipmi_si ipmi_msghandler edd nf_conntrack_proto_sctp nf_conntrack sctp 8021q garp stp llc gb_sys usb_storage uas iTCO_wdt ioatdma pcspkr iTCO_vendor_support ixgbe igb wmi i2c_i801 mdio dca sg button container ipv6 autofs4 usbhid ehci_hcd megasr(P) usbcore processor thermal_sys
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172098] CPU 0
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172099] Modules linked in: xt_sharedlimit xt_hashlimit ip_set_hash_ipport ip_set_hash_ipportip xt_NOTRACK ip_set_bitmap_port xt_sctp nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 xt_CT arpt_mangle ip_set_hash_ipnet xt_NFLOG xt_limit xt_hashcounter ip_set_hash_ipip xt_set ip_set_hash_ip deflate ctr twofish_x86_64 twofish_common camellia serpent blowfish cast5 des_generic cbc xcbc rmd160 crypto_null af_key iptable_mangle ip_set arptable_filter arp_tables iptable_raw iptable_nat nfnetlink_log nfnetlink ipt_ULOG ipt_PORTMAP af_packet zlib zlib_deflate sha512_generic sha256_generic sha1_generic md5 icp_qa_al pcie8120 rte_kni pfe_pep virtio_rte virtio_shm virtio_vtnet virtio_uio igb_uio virtio_ring virtio uio xt_tcpudp xt_state xt_pkttype nf_conntrack_control bonding binfmt_misc iptable_filter ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip_tables x_tables mperf ipmi_devintf ipmi_si ipmi_msghandler edd nf_conntrack_proto_sctp nf_conntrack sctp 8021q garp stp llc gb_sys usb_storage uas iTCO_wdt ioatdma pcspkr iTCO_vendor_support ixgbe igb wmi i2c_i801 mdio dca sg button container ipv6 autofs4 usbhid ehci_hcd megasr(P) usbcore processor thermal_sys
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172163]
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172166] Pid: 14145, comm: gis Tainted: P 3.1.10-gb20-default #1 Intel Corporation S2600CO/S2600CO
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172170] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8102064d>] [<ffffffff8102064d>] __ticket_spin_lock+0x15/0x1b
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172178] RSP: 0000:ffff88043ee03cf0 EFLAGS: 00000293
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172180] RAX: 00000000000069bf RBX: 00000000020110ac RCX: 000000000000000e
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172182] RDX: 00000000000069bc RSI: 000000000000000e RDI: ffff88041e56a484
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172184] RBP: ffff88041e56a484 R08: ffff88041e56a740 R09: ffff8804154a5840
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172187] R10: 00007f0afce77000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff88043ee03c68
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172189] R13: ffffffff813f831e R14: ffff88041e56a484 R15: ffff88041e568280
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172192] FS: 00007f0afd70b700(0000) GS:ffff88043ee00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172194] CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172196] CR2: 00007f54f6b88098 CR3: 000000042427e000 CR4: 00000000000406f0
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172199] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172201] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172204] Process gis (pid: 14145, threadinfo ffff88037537e000, task ffff88036a8fe180)
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172205] Stack:
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172207] ffffffff8106b766 ffffffffa05e3a1e 0000000101b72e68 ffff8808260ae680
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172213] 0000002e1e568280 ffff880420450000 ffff88041f887a00 ffff880420450000
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172218] ffffffff8192a870 0000000000000608 0000000000000000 ffffffff81928b00
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172224] Call Trace:
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172233] [<ffffffff8106b766>] do_raw_spin_lock+0x5/0x8
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172240] [<ffffffffa05e3a1e>] packet_rcv+0x254/0x2ab [af_packet]
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172257] [<ffffffff81337bbf>] __netif_receive_skb+0x2e1/0x36b
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172262] [<ffffffff81339722>] netif_receive_skb+0x7e/0x84
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172266] [<ffffffff8133979e>] napi_skb_finish+0x1c/0x31
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172277] [<ffffffffa031adee>] igb_clean_rx_irq+0x30d/0x39e [igb]
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172298] [<ffffffffa031aecd>] igb_poll+0x4e/0x74 [igb]
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172313] [<ffffffff81339c88>] net_rx_action+0x65/0x178
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172319] [<ffffffff81045c73>] __do_softirq+0xb2/0x19d
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172324] [<ffffffff813f9aac>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172329] [<ffffffff81003931>] do_softirq+0x3c/0x7b
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172333] [<ffffffff81045f98>] irq_exit+0x3c/0xac
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172337] [<ffffffff81003655>] do_IRQ+0x82/0x98
Aug 26 09:32:01 at-vie01a-cq21b kernel: [115456.172342] [<ffffffff813f24ee>] common_interrupt+0x6e/0x6e
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the backtrace, this sounds more like some sort of a bug in the `igb` network interface driver or the network packet driver `af_packet`. Your `gis` userland process is probably the main thing that talks to the network on that machine, so it appears connected, but soft lockups are really kernel space bugs.

As a first step I'd suggest examining the changelog for the driver in later kernels, to see if it's worth doing a kernel upgrade. In general, 3.1.x was released a while ago, and it's not marked as a stable or a longterm kernel at http://www.kernel.org/, so you'd be well advised to switch to one that is (e.g. 3.2.x is still marked 'longterm' these days), unless you're paying someone to maintain that 3.1.x kernel for you that is.

If you can't find a clear reason to upgrade, find the contact information in the Linux MAINTAINERS file at https://www.kernel.org/doc/linux/MAINTAINERS and send in a bug report, and the people there will advise you better.

Comment: how can you sure about issue is in igb network interface, as last call is

Comment: Looking at the source to net/packet/af_packet.c there is a spin lock in
packet_rcv():
        spin_lock(&sk->sk_receive_queue.lock);
        po->stats.tp_packets++;
        skb->dropcount = atomic_read(&sk->sk_drops);
        __skb_queue_tail(&sk->sk_receive_queue, skb);
        spin_unlock(&sk->sk_receive_queue.lock);
        sk->sk_data_ready(sk, skb->len);
        return 0;

so it may be contention on the sk->sk_receive_queue.lock

Comment: josip can you please help me out from this issue.

Comment: @SumitGemini that's also possible, either way you should do as I suggested and get that kernel upgraded to a modicum of a current version and then if it happens again, contact the maintainers. I'll include the links above.

Comment: but i will update igb driver first as i saw there is no changing in new version of kernel in net/packet/af_packet.c file. might be your doubt to igb driver is right. But could you tell me why did you suspect igb first?

Comment: @SumitGemini from experience, because that's a somewhat specific part of the code path, one that deals with specific hardware etc. It's less likely that the generic code paths suffer from such bugs because I presume every NIC driver tests them, so they're more likely to be ironed out.

Comment: sorry been away, today i have started this issue again, i have to clear one thing, according to dump trace, two process gis and kni_thread accessed igb driver and proceeded further, and now all three process stuck at packet_rcv() function, so my curiosity to know, could be any relation between igb driver and packet_rcv(). because if there is an issue in igb driver, how can these 2 process proceed further?

Comment: @SumitGemini those could be separate incidents, they're two seconds apart; if a shared resource got locked, each of those clients would get stuck and report its own lockup. Either way, I still recommend the best way forward would be to ask the Linux kernel networking people for help, via the netdev@vger.kernel.org mailing list.

Comment: i'm not able to send query to netdev@vger.kernel.org, Gmail showing mail subsystem delivery failed error. Is there any other way to send query to them?

Comment: i forgot to tell one more thing, our client has multiple customers and only 1 or 2 customer faced this issue, this issue is also redundant. is there any other way to produce crash dump?

Comment: What exactly is the error message within the delivery failed error? Look for the reason, possibly preceded by the number 500 or so.

Comment: "Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain vger.kernel.org by vger.kernel.org. [209.132.180.67]."

Comment: And after that?

Comment: The error that the other server returned was:
550 5.7.1 Content-Policy reject msg: The message contains HTML subpart, therefore we consider it SPAM or Outlook Virus.  TEXT/PLAIN is accepted.! BF:<H 0>; S1751561AbcKBFZd

Comment: You can get around that easily, resend the message in plain text only, see e.g. http://smallbusiness.chron.com/turn-off-html-gmail-composer-40114.html

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved this deadlock. the issue was in dpdk source code. kni_thread module is used for dpdk to connect user application with network kernel stack.

kernel: [115455.404215] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#31 stuck for 23s! [kni_thread:6605].

kni_thread was call from kthread that was usercontext and it was calling interrupt context function.